# Python the CPU consumption not down when sleep()

Tags: python, cpu, consumption

My code has two jobs, the first consumes CPU 0.3%, the second consumes CPU 80%. The two jobs are repeatly worked like this:

```
while True:
  job1()
  job2()
```

I find after the first loop, the CPU consumption not down even if it worked in job1(), the consumption is always 80%.

So I modified the code like so:

```
n = 0
while True:
  n += 1
  if n > 1:
    print 'to sleep'
    time.sleep(100000000)
    continue
  job1()
  job2()
```

I find the CPU consumption is 80% when it in `sleep()`. Why did it happen?

Comment: I don't understand your second bit of code.  It seems like it will run the jobs once, then on every subsequent loop it will sleep then `continue` which skips the jobs, and sleep again, never doing any useful work.  And the `sleep` duration is three years?!

Comment: @JohnZwinck I'm guessing the OP figured that should be long enough to figure out why the CPU stays pretty high.

Comment: I want to check the CPU consumption not down even it in sleep()

Comment: Maybe `job2()` never returns?  You could put some print statements in to check this.  But certainly `time.sleep()` is not eating your CPU cycles.

Comment: I am sure job2 returned. I guess maybe job2 imported some modules, and the modules will eat a lot CPU when the python doing the garbage collections in the background(asyncronism).

Answer (score 0):

The `sleep()` function suspends execution of the process, which means that the [process scheduler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_%28computing%29#Process_scheduler) can schedule other jobs for execution on the CPU. This could explain the high usage percentage, especially if you have other CPU-hungry tasks running in the background.

It would be helpful to know how you measure the CPU usage.